# Wpf 8.1 HubSection

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1

I have Button in Grid in HubSection, I want change Button.Content after click from kg to ibs and after secound clik from ibs to kg

This is my declaration in XAML

`<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="220,-19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                FontSize="18" Loaded="buttonWeight_Loaded" Click="buttonWeight_Click"/>`

This is my Loaded method

```
private void buttonWeight_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _buttonWeight = (Button)sender;
        _buttonWeight.Click += buttonWeight_Click;
    }
```

And click method

```
private void buttonWeight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

if ((_buttonWeight.Content)as String ==this.kg)
{
    _buttonWeight.Content = this.ibs;
}
else { _buttonWeight.Content = this.kg; }

}
```

After click i always have ibs why?

Comment: kg = resourceLoader.GetString("Kg");
 ibs = resourceLoader.GetString("Ibs");

Comment: There are declaration as String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're registering to listen to the Click event twice.  Once in the xaml declaration of your button:

```
Click="buttonWeight_Click".
```

and once in the Loaded event:

```
_buttonWeight.Click += buttonWeight_Click;
```

Get rid of either of them and you're code works.